# Magento Admin Panel Error - Empty main table name

Tags: magento

Magento 1.6.1.0 with EcomDev_UrlRewrite by Ivan Chepurnyi.

When saving a product in the admin panel or via php script $product->save() I receive this error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Empty main table name'

I believe it is a issue with EcomDev_UrlRewrite as Oguz has referenced it this post:
[Magento Admin Panel: Empty main table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153972/magento-admin-panel-empty-main-table-name/8595980#8595980)

Answer (score 0):

The problem related with "Magento Compiler", you should disable magento compiler or first install everything ( include extensions ) then enable magento compiler. But, be careful, mostly that doesn't work with compiler, it's up to you.